# Sortable plugin to sort images with drag and drop transition

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to sort a list of images - allowing to drag and drop the images as is.
With the following code, i see the dom elements being reordered when i try drag and drop, however, actual drag and drop is not visible and it is a very jarred experience.
Could you tell me what I am missing here?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
img{
margin:10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <ul class="sort-photos">
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x100" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/60x100" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/70x100" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x100" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/90x100" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-sortable/0.9.13/jquery-sortable-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".sort-photos").sortable();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/unodurga/tn8kuzab/